# Window LocationChanged firing behavior

Tags: c#, wpf

In my app I am listening to Window.LocationChanged.  On my machine, and some others this fires only after the window move is complete (the user releases the mouse after dragging from the title bar).  On some users machine this fires continuously while the window is being dragged.

Why is there a difference, and what should the expected behavior be?

Comment: Is the widow content always shown on all machines? As there usually is a performance option regarding that in Windows, possibly responsible for that

Comment: This is what @H.B. is referring to: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/75059-show-window-contents-outline-while-dragging.html

Comment: Had the same thought as H.B. so i tested it with a win8 and showing the content all the time, it gets fired the whole time. So this might be actually the problem. Especially for windows wpf has to make some strange workarounds to fit properly with the underlying windows api. I guess thats why even while its called Changed not Changing, it still fires all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested my theory that "Show window contents while dragging" (performance options) affects this. If the content is not shown the event does not fire multiple times.

Comment: That's not it.  Focus on "window contents".  It affects the way a scrollbar works.

Comment: @HansPassant: How are scrollbars related to this?

Comment: The option controls whether the window content visibly scrolls while you drag the scrollbar thumb.  On by default on all modern Windows versions.  Really old and slow machines benefit from having it off so they don't have to do a lot of painting.  Doesn't have anything to do with moving a window.

Comment: I don't know about the scrollbar issue, but the performance option H.B. described does change the event behavior as indicated.